# how to import a .sql file to mysql without selecting the database in wamp

Tags: mysql, sql, wamp

i have a .sql file that has many CREATE DATABASES, so i was looking for a command line to import my database that i dont need to select the database, because in my .sql file already has the CREATE DATABASES, i'm working with wampp, someone knows how to do that ?

Comment: A small example of your .sql script would be handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are logged into the mysql client, you can use `\. file_name`

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

If you only want to create a bunch of databases, without `CREATE TABLE` or `INSERT` statements, then you can use `USE mysql;`. But, if your .sql script contains any `CREATE TABLE` or `INSERT` statements, you must use a `USE database_name;` statement beforehand.

Comment: it's giving a error 1046, no database selected, do you have some idea ? tanks

Comment: You have to specify which database to use. If you aren't inserting data and only creating databases, then you can use `use mysql;`. If you are inserting data, after you create the databases, then you will need to use a `use database_name;` statement.